# Python nice print

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

> G O S J A J E K R A L J

I would like to print it like this:

> ['G', 'O', 'S', 'J', 'A'....

I tried with:

```
print s,
print list(s),
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
>>> l = "G O S J A J E K R A L J"
>>> l.split()
['G', 'O', 'S', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'J']
>>> ''.join(l.split())
'GOSJAJEKRALJ'
```

Comment: add a print statement after `l.split()`?

Comment: @ttwis `l.replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to split a string given the string and the delimiter that you wish to split on; in this case the space character. Python provides functionality to do this using the `split` method. A couple examples are as follows:

```
>>> s = "A B C D E"
>>> t = "A:B:C:D:E"
>>> s.split(" ")
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> t.split(":")
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to split the string -

```
>>> s = "G O S J A J E K R A L J"
>>> s.split()
['G', 'O', 'S', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'J']
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be the same: use split for that.

But another solution (for the fun) is `[x for x in l if x != ' ']`

```
>>> l = "G O S J A J E K R A L J"
>>> [x for x in l if x != ' ']
['G', 'O', 'S', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'J']
>>> l.split()
['G', 'O', 'S', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'J']
```